# What is the matrix representation of T with respect to these two bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Really tried to format it on here, but it looked horrible...

I need help understanding what exactly [The boxed section of the question is asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM6zZ.jpg). I understand how to find B and it makes sense, but obviously the same method wont work for finding the matrix representation for C. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Some hint in formatting can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Given a vector $v$ in $B$-coordinates, firstly convert them in standard coordinates, i.e., compute $B^{-1}v$.  Next multiply that vector by $A$. Hence the desired matrix is $AB^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a matrix for a linear transformation, requires us to assume or specify *a priori*, a choice of basis, on *both* the domain space as well as the codomain space. Once this is done, we can write the matrix down *with respect to these bases*. Here we have $T : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ but we will specify a more general setting.

---

Let $S : V \to W$ be  a linear transformation, and let $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ and $\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ be bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively. This is how you would write down the matrix of $T$.  It will have $m \times n$ dimensions.

> Fix  $1 \leq i \leq n$. Find $S(a_i)$. Since $b_1,...,b_n$ forms a basis for the codomain, there are *unique* coefficients $c_1,...,c_m$ so that $S(a_i) = c_1b_1 + ... +  c_mb_m$. *Then, the $\mathit{i}$th column of $\mathit{S}$ is the column vector $\mathit{[c_1,...,c_m]^T}$*. Do this for every $i$, and putting the columns together you will get the matrix of $S$.

---

Now, in part $(a)$, no bases are specified. This usually means that on both vector spaces *the canonical basis* $e_i$  ($1$ in the $i$th position and zero elsewhere) is put, and then we write the matrix with respect to these bases. You have done this correctly.

---

In part $(b)$, a basis for the domain is specified. So the canonical basis for codomain remains. That is, just find $T(b_1)$, get the coefficients of $x,y,z$ out in to get the first column, and then put all the $T(b_i)$ together to get the matrix.

---

In part $(c)$, a basis for the *codomain* is specified, so you have to now assume that we have the canonical basis for the domain space. So what you have to do is this : find $T(e_1)$, where $e_1 = (1,0,0)$, and find the unique coefficients so that $T(e_1) = c_1(1,2) + c_2(1,3)$. Then, $[c_1,c_2]^T$ is the first column of $T$. Do the same with $e_2$ and $e_3$ to get the other columns , and put them together to get the answer.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: In part (c) since the basis of my codomain is specified, I have to alter the columns in my "canonical" matrix representation of T to represent some combination of basis C? meaning T(e1) will represent the first column of "A" {T(u) = Au} and c1 and c2 will be coordinates representing some linear combination of the basis C? Thanks you so much!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you like, I can also post only the answers to question $(b)$ and $(c)$ so that you can check your progress.